# Query for repayment amount on certain months?

Tags: sql

I have two tables as described below:

Table contract:

| contract_id | total_loan | interest | contract_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 150 | 50 | Active |
| 122 | 400 | 25 | Finished |
| 133 | 750 | 0 | Inactive |
| 144 | 550 | 50 | Active |

Table ledger:

| ledger_id | contract_id | due_date | loan_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1jk | 111 | 2021-07-01 | 25 |
| 2pl | 111 | 2021-08-14 | 75 |
| 1bd | 111 | 2021-08-25 | 50 |
| 7mn | 122 | 2021-07-20 | 100 |
| 6gf | 122 | 2021-08-11 | 150 |
| 9kt | 122 | 2021-09-16 | 75 |
| 5sz | 122 | 2021-10-05 | 75 |
| 3am | 133 | 2021-10-18 | 750 |
| 8hw | 144 | 2021-09-22 | 550 |

I need a query to calculate the total repayment (sum of loan_amount + interest) for each contract id which contract status is not "Inactive", but only for months on August, September and October.

Expected output:

| contract_id | total_repayment |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 175 |
| 122 | 325 |
| 144 | 600 |

Comment: You just made the statement "I need a query". What did you try to write it yourself? Why did it fail?  What DBMS are you using (see details on the tag `sql`) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL`,then we can use [**MONTH()**](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php) to do it

```
SELECT a.contract_id,(a.interest + b.loan_amount) as total_repayment
FROM 
 contract a JOIN ledger b ON a.contract_id=b.contract_id
WHERE a.contract_status!='Inactive' 
      AND MONTH(b.due_date) IN(8,9,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server solution

```
SELECT c.contact_id, SUM(l.interest) + SUM(loan_amount) AS total_repayment
FROM ledger AS l
JOIN contract AS c ON l.contract_id = c.contract_id
WHERE c.contract_status NOT LIKE 'inactive'
    AND datename(month, l.due_date) IN ('August', 'September', 'October')
GROUP BY c.contact_id;
```

Here you can see that I used datename and passed 2 params to it the first param will represent the part of the date you want to extract and the second is the column name.

You could also look at the [DateName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) function